# How does separating fetching function into a service improve software architecture in Flutter repository pattern?

Tags: flutter, service, repository

[Simple Diagram Illustrating the Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fH7PQ.png)

When I was learning about the repository pattern, I included a function in the repository to fetch data from the server.

However, when I examined code examples from Amazon's senior Solutions Architect, I noticed that they placed the fetching function in a separate file called "Service" and allowed the repository to retrieve the data from the service.

[You can see the code here : github](https://github.com/offlineprogrammer/flutter_quiz_app/blob/main/lib/common/services/quiz_service.dart)

What's the benefit of separating fetching function?

I asked that to ChatGPT but the answer is kind of ambiguous.

Here is the answer from chatGPT:

1. **Decoupling**: Decoupling is a fundamental principle of software architecture which states that different aspects of an application should rely as little as possible on one another. By putting your fetching function in a separate service, you ensure that the rest of your code doesn't need to know how data is fetched. It only needs to know that it can ask the service for data and get a response. This makes it easier to change the fetching function without affecting other parts of your code.
2. **Reusability**: Once you've defined a service that can fetch data, you can use it in multiple places within your application. This is particularly beneficial if you find yourself needing to fetch data in the same way in different parts of your application.
3. **Abstraction**: A service provides an abstraction for a particular function of an application, such as fetching data. This makes the code easier to reason about, because you can think in terms of higher-level concepts (like a "data fetching service") rather than having to understand all the details of how data is fetched.
4. **Testability**: Separating the fetching function into its own service makes it easier to test. You can write tests for the fetching function independently of the rest of your application, and you can mock the service when you're testing other parts of your application that depend on it.
5. **Maintainability**: Over time, as requirements change, it may be necessary to change how data is fetched. If your fetching logic is scattered throughout your codebase, making such a change can be difficult and error-prone. But if all your fetching logic is in one place—in a service—it's much easier to make changes.